# How do I transition from a UIView to a UITableViewController using an IBAction in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I built my app as a single view application and then later added another view with an .xib. I get how to do that. But what I need to do now is add another view, but this is a UITableViewController that uses storyboards. I am adding IAP from a tutorial I used that uses a MasterViewController and automatically loads the first view, but I didn't make my app that way.

If anyone can explain how I can make it so when you click a button (IBAction) on my original view, I can transition to the UITableViewController that use storyboards that has the table for my IAP, that would be awesome. Is this even possible? If there's another way I'm cool with that too! BTW I am very new to this so please explain in simple terms if possible. So if anyone ca help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest you decide if you want to use NIBs (the .xib files) or storyboards, and just stick with one approach or the other throughout the app. And if you're ok supporting only iOS 5 and higher, I'd argue that storyboards are a little more intuitive, but use whatever you want. If you have everything on one storyboard, see Rob's answer below (no relation to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a button on the first form, hold down CTRL and drag the mouse and point to the other form and it will create a segue. You can set the type (push, modal, etc.)

Watch the WWDC session from 2011 introducing Storyboards. Worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When you say drag from one form to another, do you mean within the storyboard canvas? I am trying to take an IBAction and when you click the button it tranistion my .xib into a view from the storyboard. Is that possible? Forgive me if I'm wording this poorly.

Comment: Yeah, on the storyboard canvas, hold control, click on the source form and drag to the target.